# How to reorder/move items in QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am in the process of writing a Media Player application using Qt 5.8/QML with a C++ back end, and I am creating a queue of the next several songs. In order for the user to reorder the songs in the list, I need to move the items within the [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) that is filtering them. Is this possible without editing the [sourceModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#setSourceModel)? Additionally, the movement should trigger the [move](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#move-prop) transition on the [qml listview](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) to animate the movement of the items. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the QAbstractItemModel::moveRow method and the QAbstractItemModel::beginMoveRows and endMoveRows methods.

```
void MyProxyModel::moveUp(const int itemIndex) {
    if(itemIndex > 0 && itemIndex < rowCount())
    {
        beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), itemIndex, itemIndex, QModelIndex(), 
        itemIndex - 1);
        moveRow(QModelIndex(), itemIndex, QModelIndex(), itemIndex - 1);
        endMoveRows();
    }
}

void MyProxyModel::moveDown(const int itemIndex) {
    if(itemIndex >= 0 && itemIndex < rowCount() - 1) 
    {
        beginMoveRows(QModelIndex(), itemIndex, itemIndex, QModelIndex(), 
        itemIndex + 2);
        moveRow(QModelIndex(), itemIndex, QModelIndex(), itemIndex + 2);
        endMoveRows();
    }
}
```